# Visualizing graph database

Tags: neo4j, visualization, cypher

Assuming i am working with `neo4j`, the only way i can think of that would visualize my mock up data is to generate `cypher` code and paste it into neo4j's `data browser`

Is there another (better, simplier?) way one can use to create visualization without using `cypher`? Generating `cypher` code seems like a complex enough task by itself.

Writing tests is of course another way of making sure relationships are set up right, but as i am learning the system, i'd like to visually see things to make sure they are set up as expected.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This [gist](https://gist.github.com/2652082) contains an example on how to use the Neo4J Graphviz component to generate output in Graphviz DOT notation, which is supported by a range of graph visualizing software. (And of course [Graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org/) itself)

(Link to the original blog post where I found the example: http://blog.neo4j.org/2012/05/graph-this-rendering-your-graph-with.html)

Comment: Is this the right jar for the Graphviz? neo4j-graphviz-1.8.M07.jar

Comment: The latest should be neo4j.graphivz-1.8, according to http://grepcode.com/project/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.neo4j/neo4j-graphviz/

Answer (score 4):

There is a new solution to explore the content of a Neo4j graph database using a web browser: http://linkurio.us/

It allows you to search nodes by properties, inspect nodes, expand neighborhood...

Disclamer: I'm co-founder of Linkurious and Gephi.

Answer (score 3):

There are some options listed on http://www.neo4j.org/develop/visualize also.